# How can i change the XmlHttpRequest or FileAPI used in html5uploader to support IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I perfectly integrate [html5uploder](http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/) in a website I developed, however it was not designed to work with IE. But the client now wants atleast IE 10 supported. Even though IE has support for FileAPI the Drag and Drop file uploader doesnt work with any IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is no major issue with IE, this code is easily adaptable to Microsoft browser.

Make first sure that, on the html file, you force your browser to the "IE10" (or more) mode (no quirk, no compatibility mode). If not, all the javascript will fail since most of the code was not compliant with IE9:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

of course, it is not taken into account in the other browsers, so no problem.

Now, lets modify a bit the html5uploader.js file:

- First `readAsBinaryString` is not accepted in IE10. You can replace it by `readAsDataURL`, but this will change the way you submit your file, so also the way you have to received it (in php)

  ```
  if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {  
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
  } else {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }
  ```
- Second, `sendAsBinary` does not work on IE, and not relevant since we are using now `readAsDataURL`. So we have to submit our file as a base64 string that we will convert to binary after (in php). Just send it with `xhr.send`
- Finally, `btoa` is a function implemented by Mozilla and also available in Chrome. Cannot be used in IE10 I think. But no problem, since `readAsDataURL` will read your file as a base64 string ! So just send it with `xhr.send((bin));`

So it gives:

```
    if(xhr.sendAsBinary != null) { 
        xhr.sendAsBinary(body);
        // Chrome and IE10 sends data but you must use the base64_decode on the PHP side
    } else {
    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {  
      xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true&browser=IE&filename='+encodeURI(file.name), true);
    } else {
      xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true&browser=chrome&filename='+encodeURI(file.name), true);
    }
      xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-FILENAME', file.name);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-SIZE', file.size);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-TYPE', file.type);

    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {  
      xhr.send((bin)); // in IE, it s already base64, no need conversion
    } else {
      xhr.send(window.btoa(bin)); // in Chrome, it s binary, so conversion to base64 is needed
    }
    }
```

note that on the server side, I cannot get the header with `getallheaders()` because this function does not work on IIS and PHP 5.2, so I transfer the file name directly through the URL !

So now we have 3 cases in PHP:

- Firefox will send as a binary, easy to get with `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']` then move it.
- in IE, we get `$_GET['browser']=='IE'`.

we get the content of the file like that:

```
      $content = file_get_contents('php://input'); //the string we get contains 2 parts
      $content = str_replace(' ','+',$content); // we need to replace spaces by plusses
      $content = split(",",$content); // we do not need the first part of the string (the one with the file type).
      $content = base64_decode($content[1]); // we decode the base64 to binary
```

- in Chrome, we get `$_GET['browser']=='chrome'`.

we get the content of the file like that:  `$content = base64_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` //easy because it is already a binary file encoded to base64, so just need to decode it !

For both IE and chrome, we create the file with:

```
      $filename = urldecode($_GET['filename']); // because I cannot get headers...
      file_put_contents($upload_folder.'\\'.$filename, $content);
```

DONE !

Answer (score 0):

You approach works for me. I remove IE specific conditions from JS and server. It works on IE10, IE11, Chrome.

Javascript

```
private onFileChange(e) {
  var file = _.first(e.target.files);
  if (!file) { return; }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", '/upload', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Session-Id", 'secret');

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(){
    xhr.send(this.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

On Rails server

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    file_id = DateTime.current.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_%L') + '_' +
              SecureRandom.hex

    base64_content = request.body.read.to_s.split(',').last
    file_content = Base64.decode64(base64_content)

    File.open("tmp/#{file_id}", 'wb'){ |f| f.write(file_content) }

    render json: { id: file_id }
  end
end
```