# How can i use XmlHttpRequest or FileAPI in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, html5-filesystem

Below code is from the html5uploader and it works well on all browsers except IE 10. 
I have tried my best to include a function where IE is detected and the dropped file read but was unable to get this working in IE.

How do i modify code in the function below to include Internet Explorer 10?

Full Javascript code [here](http://pastebin.com/getZrPpS). 
Link to uploader [here](http://code.google.com/p/html5uploader/).

```
    // Firefox 3.6, Chrome 6, WebKit
    if(window.FileReader) { 

        // Once the process of reading file
        this.loadEnd = function() {
            bin = reader.result;                
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true', true);
            var boundary = 'xxxxxxxxx';
            var body = '--' + boundary + "\r\n";  
            body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='upload'; filename='" + file.name + "'\r\n";  
            body += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";  
            body += bin + "\r\n";  
            body += '--' + boundary + '--';      
            xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
            // Firefox 3.6 provides a feature sendAsBinary ()
            if(xhr.sendAsBinary != null) { 
                xhr.sendAsBinary(body); 
            // Chrome 7 sends data but you must use the base64_decode on the PHP side
            } else { 
                xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true&base64=true', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-FILENAME', file.name);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-SIZE', file.size);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('UP-TYPE', file.type);
                xhr.send(window.btoa(bin));
            }
            if (show) {
                var newFile  = document.createElement('div');
                newFile.innerHTML = 'Loaded : '+file.name+' size '+file.size+' B';
                document.getElementById(show).appendChild(newFile);             
            }
            if (status) {
                document.getElementById(status).innerHTML = 'Loaded : 100%<br/>Next file ...';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you been debugging in IE10?  Where is it failing?  Are there any errors?

Comment: Indeed, IE10 has a perfectly reasonable debugger built into it, and IE has always reported actual errors (though not always conveniently).

Comment: Above code was never designed for IE10. However IE10 uses the same XHR object for sending data [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When i drop the files in IE 10 upload does not take place but on other browsers it works. Should i modify the function in any way for it to happen on IE10?

Comment: It works now after I ended up using filepicker.io :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this can help other people, even if the problem is resolved for you:

1) be sure you force your browser to IE10 : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

2) don't use `reader.readAsBinaryString(file);` but `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` for IE

3) send the XHR object with `xhr.send` and do not use `btoa` (just do `xhr.send((bin));`)

4) Generally, in order your code to be comptatible with all browser, use `if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") { ... }` and open your XHR object with a different target for each browser (like this: `xhr.open('POST', targetPHP+'?up=true&browser=IE', true);` ), because if will be handled differently by PHP.

Everything is explained here : [How can i change the XmlHttpRequest or FileAPI used in html5uploader to support IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997943/how-can-i-change-the-xmlhttprequest-or-fileapi-used-in-html5uploader-to-support/18737014#18737014)